# PHP Symfony2: Delete a temp file after response

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

I have a controller that generates an image and returns the image in the response.

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

...

/**
 * @Rest\Get("/image/{name}")
 */
public function getImage($name) {
    $imageService = $this->get('image.service');
    $tempImage = $imageService->genImage($name);
    return new BinaryFileResponse($tempImage);
}
```

This works great but temp image never gets deleted.

How do I delete the temp image after the response is sent?

Comment: What does your image.service code do?

Comment: `I have a controller that generates an image` - Wrong place to do that.

Comment: unlink on the file?

Comment: @AlvinBunk, the service it makes an image with the users name on it

Comment: @BentCoder, The controller doesn't really do the work, the service does, and it only takes a few milliseconds. If there is a better way to load server generated content based on the user request, I'm up for changing the implementation. That is probably a different question though.

Comment: @jeremy, The issue is if I call unlink before the return then the image is disposed of and I don't have any data to send back to the client, and I cant really call unlink after the return. There must be some hook to remove the image after

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I read though the implementation of BinaryFileResponse. Turns out there is a public method deleteFileAfterSend

I just need

```
return (new BinaryFileResponse($tempImage))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```